# avoid temp variable using forEach

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to transform this

```
const data = {
  "title": {
    "color": "red",
    "value": "Hello World"
  },
  "category": {
    "color": "blue",
    "value": "News"
  }
}
```

to `{title: "Hello World", category: "News"}`.

Not sure I overcomplicate thing, I did this

```
let temp = {}
Object.keys(data).forEach(o=>{
  temp = {...temp, [o]: data[o].value}
})
console.log(temp)
```

It worked but I have to declare one temp variable, is there anywhere I can improve above code?

Comment: nothing wrong with the temp variable at all

Comment: @BrianOgden want to practice 'functional'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign()` and `map()` methods with spread syntax `...`

```js
const data = {"title":{"color":"red","value":"Hello World"},"category":{"color":"blue","value":"News"}}

const result = Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(data).map(e => ({[e]: data[e].value})))
console.log(result)
```

You can also use `reduce()` with `Object.assign()` instead of `map()`.

```js
const data = {"title":{"color":"red","value":"Hello World"},"category":{"color":"blue","value":"News"}}

const result = Object.keys(data).reduce((r, e) => Object.assign(r, {[e]: data[e].value}), {})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: wow the reduce solution is slick but why not use spread instead of object assign?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, using a temporary variable is not an inherently bad thing, especially if it makes your intent clearer.

```
let unpacked = {};

for (let key in data) {
  unpacked[key] = data[key].value;
}
```

This also prevents you from needing to make a new copy of the whole object for each key in your iteration.

Comment: agree this is much more readable than most of those fancy method.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Object.keys(data).reduce((temp,o)=>{return {...temp,[o]: data[o].value} }, {})
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18580140)

Comment: @AdrianPreuss I don't see any link in the answer. ??